# firebaseui image not loading

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebaseui, android-glide

My image named "pic" under the folder **contact** (static string) doesn't want to load and I get an error. I have been looking for hours for a solution but I can't retrieve any pic from firebase storage.

```
  E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    Object does not exist at location.
                     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}
                    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}
```

This is the error that I get ^

```
private void displayContactDetails() throws IOException {
            //showing the uploaded image in ImageView using the download url
            runOnUiThreadUnlessDestroyed(()->{
                Glide.with(this /* context */)
                        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                        .load(storageRef.child(contact+"/pic"))
                        .into(toolbarAvatar);
                });
```

Comment: What's the full path of the file in Storage (the value of `contact+"/pic"`)?  Can you see it in that path in the console?

Comment: contact is a static string, but I think there's a problem with it. Because I put the image in the outer folder and instead wrote .child("pic.jpg") and it worked. I guess I have to fix that contact variable. thanks